# WinForm не отображаются элементы формы пока идет загрузка

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Было реализовано некое приложение, Programm просто вызывал форму.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
```

В MainForm идет загрузка данных из бд, что требует некоторого времени. Решил реализовать форму загрузки, чтобы пользователь понимал, что программа грузится.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new LoadingForm());
    }
}
public partial class LoadingForm : Form
{
    public LoadingForm() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void LoadingForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
        thread.Start();
    }
    void ThreadMethod()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                MainForm form = new MainForm();
                form.Show();
                this.Hide();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

И вот тут появилась проблема, элементы на LoadingForm не отображаются, пока идет загрузка MainForm. Как только загружается MainForm, элементы отображаются нормально. Для понятия проблемы прикрепил скрины.

[image: PrintScreen]

Comment: Выходите в другой поток, чтобы опять потом в него вернуться, бесполезное действие. А где код самой загрузки то? Где работа с прогресс-баром, код, из-за которого проблема, где?

Comment: `this.Hide();` если эта форма больше не нужна, ее надо закрыть, а не спрятать, иначе приложение повиснет в памяти, когда надо будет его закрыть. Еще у вас хвост виляет собакой, основное окно должно формой загрузки управлять, а не наоборот.

Comment: @aepot с progressbar никакой работы нету, там style = marquee, просто показывает пользователю, что программа "думает". Зависания нету, так как по закрытию основного окна я закрываю приложение а не только форму. Вопрос, почему элементы loadingform не отображаются, пока идет загрузка.

Comment: может я немного неясно описал проблему, пока mainform грузит данные, я думал, что loadingform будет просто прокручивать progressbar. но ни label, ни progressbar не отображаются, пока грузится mainform.